# DropBox Saver: Button is not showing up. (Angular 6)

Tags: angular6, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I have tried everything but the exact same code works for the standalone application.
Here is the code for Profile component:

```
<app-header (sendUserdata)="getUserdata($event)" (sendToken)="getToken($event)" > </app-header>


<div id="wrapper">
                <!-- Sidebar -->
                <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a (click)="onClick('myProfile')"> My Profile </a>
                        </li>
                        <li> 
                            <a (click)="onClick('addPassword')">Add Password</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Show Password</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a (click)="logOut()">Logout</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>


                </div>
                <div *ngIf="myProfile">
                <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12" >
                                    <h1>Hello, {{userData.ofa}}</h1>
                                     <img src="{{userData.Paa}}" alt="">  
                                     <p>{{userData.U3}}</p> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>


                    <div *ngIf="addPassword">
                                <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                                        <div class="container-fluid">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12" >
                                                                <div class="container">
                                                                                <h1>Submit Password</h1>
                                                                                <form>
                                                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label for="name">Application Name</label>
                                                                                    <input #applicationname type="text" class="form-control" id="" required >
                                                                                  </div>

                                                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                                                    <label for="alterEgo">Username</label>
                                                                                    <input #username type="text" class="form-control" id="username" required>
                                                                                  </div>

                                                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                                                                <label for="alterEgo">Password</label>
                                                                                                <input #password type="text" class="form-control" id="password" [value]="randomPassword">
                                                                                              </div>

                                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="generatePassword()">Generate Random Password</button>
                                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success dropbox-saver" (click)="submitData(applicationname.value,username.value,password.value)">Submit</button>

                                                                               <hr> <a href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/deroi5nwm6u7gdf/advice.png" class="dropbox-saver"></a>
                                                                                </form>

                                                                            </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    </div>   
            </div>
```

Here is the output if I run the exact same code as standalone application.

[check screenshot of standalone app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBDgx.jpg)

Here is the output of the profile component where Save to Dropbox button is not showing up:

[Not Working button after login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmTCo.jpg)

At the same time, the button is showing up on the main page, where user hasn't logged in yet.

I have tried checking without all the bootstrap classes and divisions. But, I am unable to get it working.

Comment: Are you getting any error/output in the JavaScript console? How are you loading dropins.js (per [docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/saver))?

Comment: Hi Greg, Yes I am loading dropin.js as described in the document. and I am not getting any error/output in console.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what the issue might be. Please update your post with more complete steps to reproduce the issue, such as by including a sample project that demonstrates the issue.